# How do I find the point of failure for a partially unresponsive site?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7

IIS7 on Server 2008 is responding to request from some locations (mine of course) but not others (a client of course).  The problem is intermittent.  The client location having the issue has worked at times but other times not.

I have verified via wireshark that I am receiving the request from the client, but wireshark only shows replies to some locations.

Logs showing no issue:

- Windows firewall logs show no dropped packets.  In fact, disabling
  the firewall makes no difference.
- IIS Logs for the site (basic responses log) shows no indication that it saw the request.
- The HTTP.sys log also shows nothing for the ip address with the issue.

What do I need to do to find the cause of the problem?

I'm a bit of a server noob, so assume I could be missing something basic.

Comment: See if HTTP.sys logging catches anything: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc784703(v=WS.10).aspx

Comment: Thanks.  I loked at that, but I don't think I see anything in that log that appears to correlate with the requests in wireshark that do not get a response. Nothing in the HTTP.sys log has the same source IP.